# Queuing theory model for chain of queues and servers.

Tags: optimization, game-theory, queueing-theory

I want to apply queuing theory for our service which consists of multiple microservices which communicate via message queues.

Basically, all events from the inbound queue are processed by one or several instances of the microservice and are being put into the next queue. It goes on for like 10 steps.

Are there any models or approaches for applying queueing theory for my case? What I want is to optimize this flow by configuring order of processing, number of instances, e.t.c. to reach the required bandwidth and stability of the system.

Comment: I have some questions.

1.  Whether, in the queue-theoretic context, a "microservices" plays the role of a station that processes "customers" or not.  If a microservice is a service station, then the "customers" coming into the station form a queue.  Are the "customers" the messages to be processed?  Is that what you mean by "message queues"?

2.  Is there a single "inbound queue"?  If so, how is it decided which microservice receives the next customer from the inbound queue?

Comment: 3.  Are all service stations identical?  Doesn't sound like it, but the modeler would really need to know which messages are suitable to be processed by which microservices.  Sounds like a message has multiple phases of processing and, in each phase, needs to be fed into the right kind of microservice?  When is a message considered fully processed?  How are the microservices interconnected?  Each one to each one (probably not)?

4.  Which parameters can be configured?  Delay in the processing of the next customer?   Available microservices of a given type?  Others?

Comment: 5.  What is an "instability"?  What are the possible random perturbations, and what parameters do they affect?

Comment: @avs 1. You're right.
2. There's a single inbound queue and one service to process it. Basically, it works this way:
A service is asking a queue for new messages every second, at max 500 messages can be returned
via a single request.
(both frequency and max number of messages are configurable).
The number of services might be increased thought, however it will be instances of the same service.
So, answering your question, the first one to ask for the customer will process it.

Comment: 3. Services are interconnected via queues.
Let's say we have some system for dressing people :)
- A - B - C 

Customers come to the inbound queue (first dash)
Service A then chooses the most suitable shirt for the person and puts him into the next queue (second dash)
Service B chooses some pants, puts into the next queue (third dash)
Service C chooses the shoes and here processing is completed.

I believe this is a good analogy for my case, because basically, all microservices are enriching 
the initial message with some data.

Comment: 4. Configurable parameters: 
Let's say choosing pants is complicated and takes way more time that other tasks.
Then, we can increase the number of services processing the second queue.

- A - B1,B2 - C

Increase of performance is really dependent on the type of microservice. For some it might
be close to x2, for some - way less for various reasons. Also, consuming messages from one queue by two services 
comes with some expenses 
(because it's unacceptable to get one message processed by two services, it will cause double payments and problems like that)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92224/discussion-between---and-avs).